# Drawing of optical lens

Tags: pst-optic

Is it possible to draw only a lens and not the light beam nor any labels or axes, using [`pst-optic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-optic)?

**Update**

What is the default lens colour? In table 2 (page 9) of the [manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-optic/pst-optic-doc.pdf), nothing is mentioned of the default colour.

I didn't asked the correct question; I meant what the colour is of the lens in Gonzalo Medina's original answer. I found the answer myself; on line 168 of the [`pst-optic.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-optic/pst-optic.tex) file, we have

```
\definecolor{BleuVerre}{cmyk}{0.2,0,0,0}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for bothering you. I'll delete this comment (and the previous one) shortly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use the `drawing=false` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-optic}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-7.5,-3)(7.5,3)
\rput(0,0){\lens[lensGlass=true,lensWidth=0.5,lensType=DVG,drawing=false]}%
\rput(2,0){\lens[lensGlass=true,lensWidth=0.5,lensType=CVG,drawing=false]}%
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The default color for `lensColor` is `lightgray` (it can be found in `pst-optic.tex`).

Comment: @HarishKumar hehe! In fact, when I started using LaTeX I used PS-Tricks for my drawings, so I guess the change was (some years ago) from PS-Tricks to TikZ. It's a real shame, but I've forgotten almost everything about the powerful PS-Tricks.

Answer (score 8):

If it's about drawing a lens only, you can also use [`pst-optexp`](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-optexp/pst-optexp.pdf) for this:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,5)
  \pnodes(0,2.5){A}(10,2.5){B}
  \psset[optexp]{lensheight=4}
  \addtopsstyle{OptComp}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=blue!10}
  \lens[abspos=1, lensradius=4 4](A)(B)
  \lens[abspos=3, lensradius=-4 -4](A)(B)
  \lens[abspos=5, lensradius=4 -4](A)(B)
  \lens[abspos=7, lensradius=8 0](A)(B)
  \lens[abspos=9, lensradius=8 5, lenswidth=1](A)(B)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated comment: On the frontpage of the manual for `pst-intersect` you forgot to change the name from `pst-optexp`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg please add `edit Title` as `Improved English+Added ctan link for package` for this http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/160864/revisions . Friendly advice: In future add edit title in all your revisions to any Q & A for quick look at changes and faster grasping to Upvote the edit.

Comment: @texenthusiast Good point. I'll try to remember that.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Thanks for the hint, TheLastError also pointed me to it. I'll correct it in the next release, but I need to fix some other parts before that.

Comment: @Christoph: Thinking a bit over it: The backdraw is, that your avatar is not shown in comments.